# Can React-Native [TypeError: Network request failed] mean internet connection failure or RN fetch timeout?

Tags: react-native

Sorry I've gone through every stack overflow question of this exact same error and no one has definitely provided an answer to this.

My production app only sometimes gives this error per my reporting service, so I am thinking two things:

- Internet connection blipped out which it often does
- There's some React Native timeout or under the hood machinery that cancels the attempt if the server hasn't returned anything.

To clarify:

```
fetch().then((response) => {
   // Server returned something, even 500
}).catch((e) => {
   // Server returned nothing OR internet connection bad?
   // RN doesn't care to share why, just "I couldn't fetch"
});
```

Comment: Usually happens when your server is down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since the fetch function is a javascript function, let's see what [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Checking_that_the_fetch_was_successful.) say :

A fetch() promise will reject with a **TypeError** when a network error is encountered or CORS is misconfigured on the server side, although this usually means permission issues or similar — a 404 does not constitute a network error, for example.

Comment: Yeah I understand the official spec gives a pretty clear answer but I'm also curious if RN people can weigh in.   Mostly that somebody has to manually write the bridge code and RN can deviate from official spec.   I'll leave this post up a bit and then accept.